# How to save dynamic TextView into an ID'd string for a fos?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've coded this app to take whatever is in the EditText and put it in a TextView as a sort of "to-do" list. How can I set the TextViews that are produced to be saved into a list so that no matter how long it has been since the app has been opened it will show the same data?

This is the code I've made for the TextView so far:

```
// Adds text to the Notes section
public void sendText(View view) {
    llNotes = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llNotes);
    etNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNotes);
    String message = etNotes.getText().toString();

    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText(message);
    text.setPadding(5, 2, 2, 0);
    text.setTextSize(18);
    llNotes.addView(text);
}
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this would be the tutorial you want to read: [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Tip: To test this easily go to `System Settings` -> `Developer Settings` -> `Don't keep activities`.

Comment: Right! I actually know how to recreate an activity but what I'm curious about is when a TextView is made, I don't know how to save those specific new TextViews (created by the user). In other words, how can I get the application to identify those new TextViews to be saved?

Comment: You would do it manually, probably keeping references to the newly created TextViews and looping through them when saving and restoring. Or the other option would be to persist them to SQLite, flat file, etc. Is that what you are asking?